# How to write Junit test for methods with local variables

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have written a method which asks user to press enter to continue and timeouts after some time.
I am facing difficulty in writing Junit tests for this method use Mockito. Below is the method.

```
private static final ExecutorService l = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

private static String getUserInputWithTimeout(int timeout) {
    Callable<String> k = () -> new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
    Future<String> g = l.submit(k);
    while (ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start, LocalDateTime.now()) < timeout) {
        if (g.isDone()) {
            try {
                String choice = g.get();
                return choice;
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error("ERROR", e);
                g = l.submit(k);
            }
        }
    }
    logger.info("Timeout...");
    g.cancel(true);
    return null;
}
```

I tried mocking Callable and Future but as this method is creating them locally creating them in Test has no impact.

I tried few things but didnt work as expected I might be doing it wrong.

```
@Test
    public void testgetUserInputWithUserInput() throws Exception {
        
         Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         Callable<String> callable = PowerMockito.mock(Callable.class);
        

         ExecutorService executorServiceMock = PowerMockito.mock(ExecutorService.class);
     
         Future<String> futureMock = PowerMockito.mock(Future.class);
         when(executorServiceMock.submit(any(Callable.class))).thenReturn(futureMock);


        assertEquals("", getUserInputWithTimeout(3));
    }
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the test you've tried as well? Also, what happens when you run that test and what did you expect to happen instead? (Questions here do better with a [mcve].)

Comment: Why do you want to mock Callable and Future ? While writing JUnit tests, you are supposed to mock only the dependencies external to the code being tested. For example - mocking a Repository your code uses to save data. Objects or variables that are initialized and local to the method should not be mocked.

Comment: As this method takes user input , i wont to mock that so that my while loop ends , without it it just times out and test case is failed

Comment: Have a look how to mock `System.in` - it allows you test simulation of user behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to slightly change your method, take the callable object out of method and pass it as a parameter, this should solve your problem with mocking.

```
private static final ExecutorService l = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

private static String getUserInputWithTimeout(int timeout, Callable<String> k) {
    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.now();
    Future<String> g = l.submit(k);
    while (ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start, LocalDateTime.now()) < timeout) {
        if (g.isDone()) {
            try {
                String choice = g.get();
                return choice;
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error("ERROR", e);
                g = l.submit(k);
            }
        }
    }
    logger.info("Timeout...");
    g.cancel(true);
    return null;
}
```

Your tests should look like below :

```
@Test
public void testgetUserInputWithUserInput() throws Exception {
    
    String ENTER = " ";
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(ENTER.getBytes()));

    Callable<String> callable = () -> new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    assertEquals(ENTER, getUserInputWithTimeout(5, callable));
}
```